# Eclipse Java EE IDE need tomcat source for debugging

Tags: eclipse, debugging, tomcat

Apologies for asking this. I have googled around but am unable to find an answer.

I am using the Eclipse Java EE IDE (WTP) to debug a JSP. When stepping through the code, I get some similar exceptions thrown which all say that it cannot find the source code for a particular jar file.

I understand now that Eclipse needs the source code when debugging to allow it to step through the application. So I need to find the source code for the Tomcat installation and point eclipse to its location:

- I have checked the jar files of the Tomcat installation, and they only contain `.class` files, no source code.
- I have checked that the jar files downloaded from the Apache site also don't contain source code.
- I have downloaded source code (not in jars) from the Apache site but this does not seem to be all the source code because it has only fixed some `source code not found` exceptions but not others.
- I have downloaded a couple of jar files with source code in from [GrepCode.com](http://www.grepcode.com) but am thinking there must be another way.

This must be a common issue and I wonder if there is a way to avoid downloading the source for each jar in the tomcat installation separately?

Many thanks

Comment: Are you debugging your own code or are you debugging code in tomcat itself?

Comment: Sounds like you are debugging as a remote process instead of inside Eclipse as a Dynamic Web Project.

If at all possible, do that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you know that you can use the debugger to step over 3rd party code, rather than step into it?

It should be possible to debug your issue without stepping into the tomcat code, unless of course you think you have discovered a tomcat bug.

Generally you should step over methods in 3rd party jars, and look at the results of that method by exploring the state of your app after the method returns.

Comment: Hi Steve. Thanks for the response. I see what you mean, maybe I am doing something wrong. I know in normal Java code, I would use F5 to step *into* code and F6 to step *over* code. I am just using F6 to step over a JSP page. When I get to the HTML tag at the end, that is the point (just after) that I get the exceptions thrown. That isn't trying to step into any tomcat code is it?